# $watchCollection parameters required returns error, when passed as an array

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

Am having a small query understanding a piece of code.

I was under the impression that **$watchCollection will watch arrays**, when passed as parameter according to this syntax:

> $watchCollection(obj, listener);

My query however is in this piece of code:

```
  var exp = $parse(attrs.chartData);
  var salesDataToPlot=exp(scope);
```

which is then used in:

```
scope.$watchCollection(exp, function(newVal, oldVal){
               salesDataToPlot=newVal;
               redrawLineChart();
           });
```

"exp" is of type function, and when i tried to pass it as an array, i got the *“Cannot read property 'length' of undefined”* error.
I got that error when i tried this Code :

```
  var salesData = scope[iAttrs.chartData];

.
.
.
.

  scope.$watchCollection(salesData, function(newVal, oldVal){
                   salesDataToPlot=newVal;
                   redrawLineChart();
               });
```

Why coudn't i pass salesData as an array to $watchCollection?

**[Here's my pen](http://codepen.io/sravikiran/pen/qwgbl)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) service takes an expression, and turns it into a function, that will resolve to actual data when given a context, which is usually the scope.

```
  var exp = $parse(attrs.chartData); // exp is an expression function that needs context
  var salesDataToPlot=exp(scope); is the actual result of supplying exp with context - the scope. The result is the array you need
```

Just watch salesDataToPlot ([pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqmpeY)):

```
scope.salesDataToPlot = salesDataToPlot;

scope.$watchCollection('salesDataToPlot', function(newVal, oldVal){
               salesDataToPlot=newVal;
               redrawLineChart();
           });
```

Using salesData directly throws an error because salesData is a property on scope, and not a variable available in this closure. To make $watchCollection look for this property on the scope, you'll have to use "salesData" ([pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbPBNw)).

```
  scope.$watchCollection("salesData", function(newVal, oldVal){
                   salesDataToPlot=newVal;
                   redrawLineChart();
               });
```

Comment: i kinda knew that part, my query is why doesn't it work when i directly give salesData to watchCollection?

Comment: You have to use "salesData" to tell the watch to look for a property on the scope - see edit.

Comment: Oh that's pretty cool.
So, do correct me if am wrong, $watchCollection can take both string and function/array as the elements to be watched?

Comment: If a string is passed it just do $scope['string'].

Comment: So, if i do scope.salesData to be watched, it should be right ?

Comment: If you mean scope.$watchCollection("salesData", function() {}); then you are right.

Comment: Yup, i tried that. Which resulted in an error. :)
That was the whole point of the question.. I was actually wondering why the usage of $parse, when i can directly pass in salesData to be watched.

Comment: Let's start again - you parse the attr.chartData to get a expression function, you use scope as context (if you have a directive with isolated scope try scope.$parent instead). You assign the result to scope.salesDataToPlot. After that you watch 'salesDataToPlot', and it doesn't work?

Comment: Have updated my Pen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPoMzY

Have commented 2 lines and updated what to watch. Was wondering, why this didn't work for me.

Comment: You have two unrelated (commented), and an error in your d3 code. I commented drawLineChart() in the $watchCollection to show that the watch works - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXbpQV